# Eventhandler in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, handler, httphandler

I am a newby in MVC4.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    //GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

I want to call a handler when I write .../Stackoverflow but always Stackoverflow controller works.
How can I stop to call Stackoverflow controller? I only want to call handler.

I add below statement to the web.config.

```
  <add name="MyHandler" verb="*" path="/Stackoverflow " type="Library.MyHander"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to ignore that route, so in the `RegisterRoutes` method, add this line:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Stackoverflow");
```